# Why does using the service command work on a systemd distro?

Tags: systemd, init

I'm trying to understand the Linux init system. 
I don't understand how there are three competing systems, yet the `service` command seems to work on all of them.

From the service commands `man` page:

> service runs a System V init script or upstart job...

I'm using lubuntu 16.4 I *think* systemd is the default init system (`pstree` shows systemd as root process). Systemd is not mentioned in the man page for service. Yet I still start and stop scripts using it.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Quite a few distros provide compatability scripts to emulate sysvinit functionality during the transition so that people have time to adjust.

Comment: Or, if they're like me, keep using the old compatibility scripts and get blindsided when they're no longer supported (:

Comment: If you have a look at `/usr/sbin/service` you'll probably find it's a shell script with code to handle upstart, systemd and init.d style scripts.

Comment: Ubuntu isn't a "real" systemd distro, upstart is still there, and most of systemctl service management is still done using the old style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some distributions have opted to include compatibility scripts so that old style commands still work.  For example, on Debian 8.

```
root@matrix:~# which service
/usr/sbin/service
root@matrix:~# file /usr/sbin/service
/usr/sbin/service: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines

root@matrix:~# grep upstart /usr/sbin/service
# Operate against system upstart, not session
   && initctl version 2>/dev/null | grep -q upstart \
   # Upstart configuration exists for this job and we're running on upstart
         # Action is a valid upstart action

root@matrix:~# grep systemd /usr/sbin/service
is_systemd=
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
   is_systemd=1
          # On systems using systemd, we just perform a normal restart:
          # A restart with systemd is already a full restart.
          if [ -n "$is_systemd" ]; then
# When this machine is running systemd, standard service calls are turned into
if [ -n "$is_systemd" ]
            # the systemd service file does not (yet) support reload for a
```